# How to: Select from MYSQL text field type only the numbers that start with 89 using REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I have tried in many ways to select from text fields only the numbers that start with 89. I don't have a fix length after the first 2 numbers.

How can I do this to work properly and not get numbers like 389xxxxxx in results, for example. THE minimum length should be at least 8 characters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your column is integer, then you can probably do something like:

```
select * from my_table where cast(int_column) as char) like '89______%'
```

(that's 6 underscore characters before the percentage char)

If it's character value, then you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE char_column REGEXP "^89[[:digit:]]{6,}$"
```

If your column is numeric with decimal places and you want only integer values, then you need to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE cast(numeric_column as char) REGEXP "^89[[:digit:]]{6,}$"
```

**Edit:** It seems Tim has edited his answer, which I referred to, so I edited my answer to include his code for column of character type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "(^|[^[:digit:]])89[[:digit:]]{6,}";
```

will do this:

```
(                # Either match
 ^               # the start of the string
|                # or
 [^[:digit:]]    # any character except a digit
)                # End of alternation.
89               # Match 89
[[:digit:]]{6,}  # plus at least 6 more digits.
```

Comment: So the number is not the only content of that column?

Comment: @CosminPanait: I've modified the regex. It should meet your requirements now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP "([^0-9]89[0-9]*)|(^89[0-9]*)"
```

Comment: this is good, but I only need for numbers with length bigger that 4 or 5 characters, Thank you for your response.